# Error in Cloning a repository from windows

Tags: windows, git, git-clone

When i try to clone a repository through git from windows I get this error

> Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are connecting via the SSH protocol.
Using SSH, every host has a key.

Clients remember the host key associated with a particular address and if Key value changes You should change key value in your client also .